# Git operations from command line drop permissions for windows's git

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, phpstorm

I have ubuntu guest at windows host.

I work with phpStorm with git integrations for windows and use virtual machine as samba connected drive.

The trouble is that every time I do something at command line at my virtual machine, such as `git status`, my windows' git drops out with an exception.

[image]

Looks like permissions for files in .git folder chacnges and I have to manually restart git for windows after restoring rights `sudo chmod a+rw -R ./` in command line.

It has been happening for couple years by now and constantly repeats on different computers so I assume I do something wrong. But I can't understand what exectly goes wrong. I dont run ubuntu commands as root.

Can anyone help? May be someone else experiencing same?

phpStorm is version 10
latest git for windows 2.9.2
ubuntu 14 as guest

EDIT:
Sometimes git for windows doesnt drop out, but it still dies with message in phpStorm
[image]

Comment: Note that git doesn't track any file permissions except for the executable bit. On clone/checkout, everything will be set to the local umask.

Answer (score 1):

Finally!

After two years I've found an answer. It's simple!

I've been always downloading the LATEST version of git for windows.
But on ubuntu guest the version was old, so two gits had tooo many differences to live together on one repository. And that was causing git for windows to die.

To update git version on ubuntu:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

`sudo apt-get install git`